# MongoDB Aggregation Limit Lookup

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am using $lookup in PyMongo to successfully "join" two collections (this works). I am having a problem where the second collection I am joining in may exceed the BSON document size when it returns all of the records.

I am looking to use $limit to limit the number of records that are allowed to join under "match_docs" eg: 100 records maximum from "comments" per obj_id:

```
db.indicators.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "comments",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "obj_id",
      "as": "match_docs"
    }
  }
])
```

I've tried various types of $limit, and it seems to only limit the total number of results overall, not just for the join.

Comment: you can't set a limit in $lookup, but you don't need this to make the query work. Adding `{allowDiskUse: true}` to your aggregation option should fix the issue

Comment: @felix OP is talking about the BSON document size limit, not the memory limit.

Comment: Can you `$match` on content returned from the `$lookup` in order to reduce results? There is a special case when the pipeline stages are `$lookup` -> `$unwind` -> `$match` and the condition in `$match` (in succession ) and `$match` refers to the array from `$lookup` where the latter two stages get "hoisted" into the `$lookup`. This is an optimization to reduce the possible entries returned.

Comment: @NeilLunn do you know how this would look in query form?

Comment: Yes you have the `$unwind` **immediately** following the `$lookup`, and ideally the `$match` **imdediately** after the `$unwind`. If that makes things clearer than what I already said. Perhaps you should show your entire "intended" aggregation pipeline, then we can advise if this is a fit for your purpose.

Answer (score 35):

Starting from MongoDB 3.6 you can use uncorrelated subqueries to limit the lookup:

```
db.indicators.aggregate([
{ $lookup: {
  from: 'comments',
  as: 'match_docs',
  let: { indicator_id: '$_id' },
  pipeline: [
    { $match: {
      $expr: { $eq: [ '$obj_id', '$$indicator_id' ] }
    } },
    // { $sort: { createdAt: 1 } }, // add sort if needed (for example, if you want first 100 comments by creation date)
    { $limit: 100 }
  ]
} }
])
```

Comment: $limit after $match, exactly what I was looking

Comment: Is it just me that this doesnt work for?
Somehow instead of limiting the results from the "comments" collection, it's limiting results from the parent collection on which I'm doing the lookup

Comment: I had this same issue but the `$lookup` itself was sufficient for the match. Just needed the `$sort` and `$limit` for the lookup. Worked great.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a `$unwind` immediately following a `$lookup`, the pipeline will be optimized, basically combining the 2 stages helping to bypass the 16MB limit that could result from the `$lookup` returning a large number of documents.

Keep in mind, if a single document in the foreign collection plus the size of the document in the local collection exceed 16 MB, this optimization cannot help.

Comment: Note also that if `$unwind` is followed by `$match` which addresses the foreign collection then the query condition is also "hoisted" into the `$lookup` along with the `$unwind`. You can see this using `{ "explain": true }` as an argument to aggregate.

Comment: @NeilLunn there are some caveats to this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21612. Additionally, to use an index for the subsequent `$match`, you need to have a compound index starting with the field used for the `$lookup` followed by the field(s) in the `$match`.

Comment: Indexes have nothing to do with what I am saying here, and that's a separate issue. Both responses you have made here look like they are done by someone searching terms in google, and could be clarified to show the whole story with example.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I'm not sure I see how that is a separate issue. You stated that using a `$match` after `$lookup` and `$unwind` will be optimized. I simply added that, for the `$match` to use an index, the index must take a specific form. Otherwise, it could result in scanning a large number of documents to satisfy the `$match` from the resulting `$lookup` result set, even when optimized by the query engine. I provided the SERVER ticket link to illustrate the caveats that exist in the optimization of this pipeline.

Comment: Please provide example code.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out.

$lookup -> $match -> $project

```
db.indicators.aggregate([{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "comments"
        , "localField": "_id"
        , "foreignField": "obj_id"
        , "as": "match_docs"
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "match_docs": {
            "$exists": True
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "match_docs_agg": {
            "$slice": ["$match_docs", 3]
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Hate to burst your bubble there but that isn't actually doing anything to avoid the BSON limit being broken. It's also a "given" to test for the presence of the array field since it is "always" created in the output to `$lookup`. `$slice` will only reduce the size of the result "after" it is already pulled into the document, so the BSON limit can still be broken. The only reason this works for you is because the documents pulled in do not actually break this limit. 16MB is quite a lot anyway

Comment: You're 100% right, It was doing what I wanted in the sense that it was only returned "3" of the joined list, but it still breaks during the pipeline.

Comment: Can you instead please show the aggregation you intend to do in your question. By your "intent" I mean the `$lookup` operation, and the aggregation operations you wanted to do with the information coming next, even if it is just a `$slice`. Then I can actually show you what to do.

Comment: so how do we fix?

Answer (score -3):

This way we can filter the record by using limit aggregations. according to our requirement, we can pass the limit value. Here have a useful link [Docs link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)

```
db.getCollection('botAnalytics').aggregate([{
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "movie",
                        localField: "botKey",
                        foreignField: "key",
                        as: "botDetails",
                    },
                },
                {
                    $match: { applicationId: "15077a8c38657a61b844e6a" },
                       },
                 { $limit : 5 }])
```